# How to say "How is your little daughter?"

Tags: translation

How to say "How is your little daughter?"

Comment: Typically you should post some research and a bit more context so that the question can be considered valid. Although the question seems straight-forward, the close votes are occurring because you did not show such research. A good way to show research might have been to simply show the result that translate.google.com provides "如何为你的小女儿？" This notation of a bad translation would have been enough to make this a valid question. The good news is that you can still update the question so that it is valid. Please check the help link for how to ask valid questions on CSE.

Answer (score 4):

It's depends on the context.
If you are going to meet your old friend you can say "你小女儿怎么样？/你小女儿最近怎么样？/你小女儿近来如何？"

Answer (score 3):

Or You may also say something like: 你的小女儿最近还好吗?

English: How is your little daughter lately?

I think this is a more complete sentence and more polite.

最近 = lately

Answer (score 1):

In Cantonese, "你細女近來點呀?"

"細女" = youngest daughter

"細仔" = youngest son